# ¿Como aumentar el valor de un numero en un textbox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo este codigo

```
 private void mas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bpm++;
        bpm_textbox.Text = bpm.ToString();

    }
```

pero quiero aumentar directo el string sin tener que convertir de entero a cadena, ya que no puedo dar varias veces clic sobre el botón y que aumente rápidamente

Comment: no. no se puede sumar 1 a un string. El lenguaje no sabe sumar palabras a numeros. Me gustaria saber porque decis que no podes hacer que aumente rapidamente.. ese codigo deberia ser imperceptible.

Comment: El compilador no aumenta variables tipo `string` como si fueran números o variables `int`. Para eso debes convertirlo a tipo `int` y luego aumentarlo.

Comment: la única variante que se me ocurre es `bpm_textbox.Text = (++bpm).ToString();` pero es lo  mismo, hay que convertir el número a string para que lo tome

Comment: si notas una lentitud no es por la conversion, sino por la representacion del valor en pantalla sobre el textbox, a nivel de codigo convertir tipos no afecta la performance, menos aun en ese codigo tan simple

Comment: porque no usas el control NumericUpDown, con este aumentas sin usar variables y puedes recuperar el value, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/numericupdown-control-windows-forms

Comment: Veo que tu problema es que quieres capturar los clicks sin detener el hilo principal de tu aplicacion.   

Para un proceso tan sencillo esto no deberia impactar, pero si esas haciendo algo mas complicado despues de eso durante el mismo evento tal vez deberias investigar delegados para invocar eventos fuera del hilo principal

Comment: Los delegados en si no invocan métodos fuera del hilo principal (UI thread), un delegado es simplemente un puntero a un método. Para ejecutar métodos de forma asíncrona se requiere usar async y await.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void mas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32.Parse(bpm)
    bpm++;
    bpm_textbox.Text = bpm.ToString();

}
```

Primero debes convertir a Int tu variable bpm, dado que no puedes sumarle 1 a un String.